# Object DOMDocument should be created. with order custom attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, orders

I've followed this link  : https://www.yereone.com/blog/magento-2-how-to-add-new-order-attribute/

to add a custom attribute to my orders.

But when I check at the step before the **event** I've got this error :

> Object DOMDocument should be created.

How can I fix it ? Can't see any of my orders in backend...

Comment: Can you check log files if there is any errors?

Comment: I've found a solution, I removed sales_order_grid.xml file